# STRING_SPLIT with float values in an array

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an array which looks like this (varchar(max)):

```
[207.0, 206.8, 205.6]
```

I want to string split the values in individual rows. However, using this SQL

```
SELECT
replace(replace(replace(VALUE, '[', ''), ']', ''), ' ', '') as VALUE
FROM       TABLE
CROSS      APPLY STRING_SPLIT(VALUE, ',') AS f
```

I get this result

```
| Value            |
| ---------------- | 
| 207.0,206.8,205.6| 
| 207.0,206.8,205.6|
| 207.0,206.8,205.6|
```

How do I achieve to split the values into individual rows with unique values?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not treat is as a JSON array, seeing as that's what it appears to be.

Comment: Also, I would expect that SQL to error due to it referencing an ambiguous column. This suggests that you are in a case sensitive collation; the column returned from `STRING_SPLIT` is `value` *not* `VALUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the comma separated string to `STRING_SPLIT` :

```
SELECT *
FROM       mytable
CROSS      APPLY STRING_SPLIT(replace(replace(replace(col1, '[', ''), ']', ''), ' ', ''), ',') AS f
```

Result :

```
col1                    value
[207.0, 206.8, 205.6]   207.0
[207.0, 206.8, 205.6]   206.8
[207.0, 206.8, 205.6]   205.6
```

This is an other way to do it, using `openjson`

```
select t.col1, s.value
from mytable t
CROSS APPLY openjson(t.col1,'strict $') as s
```

Your Query work fine if you properly specify references (thanks to @Thom for the remark) :

```
SELECT t.VALUE as 'Array', 
replace(replace(replace(f.VALUE, '[', ''), ']', ''), ' ', '') as 'Element'
FROM       [TABLE] t
CROSS      APPLY STRING_SPLIT(VALUE, ',') AS f
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ppQRZIgb)

Comment: `strict $` only if you want an error if the array is empty, otherwise leave it off

Comment: As a note, what the OP has does work, if they properly qualify or reference the correct column: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NwpfYfFS)